# Find the number of ordered pairs $\left(a,b\right)$ such that $-15\le3a+b\le-5$ for integers $a$ and $b$ using the method of lattice points.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I got the inequality $-15\le3a+b\le-5$, with the condition that $-10\le a\le10$ and $-10\le b\le10$, and $a$ and $b$ are integers. Though I can solve it by bashing, I came across a video where the guy said that he solved it using lattice points on a graph, by substituting $x$ for $a$, and $y$ for $b$. I was interested to know how does this work.

Could anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the link of the video? We have to see the video in order to explain it to you.

Comment: Yes sure, it is https://youtu.be/ftqYFzzWKv8?t=843